# My job is running but no data is comming

Tags: sql, ssis, jobs

I have got a ssis package which runs when I manually run from Integration Services. But when I try to run it from a job. Then it runs but no data is seen in the data. There seems to be some permission issue. Can somebody tell me what permissions are required for running a package from a SQL Server Job?

Answer (score 1):

State the error message.

If you are using a flat file connection manager, and that's where the error is occurring, click 'start' then 'computer' then check to make sure you are mapped to that drive.  If not, click the tab upper right corner to map to the drive then when you access the file through SSIS you shouldn't have an error.

Answer (score 0):

If the package runs successfully as a job using the SQL Server Agent then you have the permissions set right for the database side.

However make sure if you are accessing any external data such as flat files that the agent is able to access these locations. You may have permissions on your Windows account to access the locations when you run the package in Visual Studio but the agent service running the job requires those permissions too.

If this is not the case can you clarify what your package does and any messages you receive from the  catalog reports so I can help further.